# Bitarr class optimization C++

Tags: c++, bitwise

I have implemented a bitarr class that does bit manipulations. I would love to know if there is any way to make the code more optimized. Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you! **Note**: int main() should not be modified.

```
    #include <iostream>    
    #include <vector>    
    #include <climits>
    #include <cstring>

    template<size_t NumBits>
    class bitarr
    {
    private:
        static const unsigned NumBytes = (NumBits + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;//find number of bytes to track least memory footprint
        unsigned char arr[NumBytes];
    public:
        bitarr() { std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)); } //initialize array to 0

        void set(size_t bit, bool val = true) {
            if (val == true)
            {
                arr[bit / CHAR_BIT] |= (val << bit % CHAR_BIT);//left shift and OR with masked-bit
            }
        }

        bool test(size_t bit) const {
            return arr[bit / CHAR_BIT] & (1U << bit % CHAR_BIT); //left shift and AND with masked-bit
        } 
        const std::string to_string(char c1, char c2)
        {
            std::string str;
            for (unsigned int i = NumBits; i-- > 0;)
                str.push_back(static_cast<char>
                ('0' + test(i)));
            while (str.find("0") != std::string::npos) {
                str.replace(str.find("0"), 1, std::string{ c1 });
            }
            while (str.find("1") != std::string::npos) {
                str.replace(str.find("1"), 1, std::string{ c2 });
            }
            return str;
        } 
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bitarr& b)
        {
            for (unsigned i = NumBits; i-- > 0; ) 
                os << b.test(i);
            return os << '\n';
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        try
        {
            bitarr<5> bitarr;
            bitarr.set(1);
            bitarr.set(2);

            const std::string strr = bitarr.to_string('F', 'T');
            std::cout << strr << std::endl;
            if (strr != "FFTTF")
            {
                throw std::runtime_error{ "Conversion failed" };
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& exception)
        {
            std::cout << "Conversion failed\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, are you aware of [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `size_t` consistently

You use both `size_t` and `unsigned` for counting. Stick with `size_t`.

## Use default member initialization

You can use [default member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) to ensure `arr[]` is initialized, without having to call `memset()`:

```
class bitarr
{
    static const unsigned NumBytes = (NumBits + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned char arr[NumBytes] = {};
    ...
};
```

You can then also remove the constructor completely.

## Unnecessary `if`-statement in `set()`

You don't need to check whether `val` is `true` in `set()`. If it is false, the body of the `if`-statement will still do the right thing. While it might look like that would do a lot of work for nothing, the processor might easily mispredict this condition, making it less efficient than not having the `if` at all.

## Make all functions that do not modify `arr[]` `const`

You made the function `test()` `const`, but `to_string()` also does not modify the bit array, so you can make that function `const` as well.

## Optimize `to_string()`

Your function `to_string()` is very inefficient. The caller provides you with the characters to use for the representation of one and zero bits, but you first ignore that and build a string of `'0'` and `'1'`, and then replace those characters one by one. Why not build the string directly using `c1` and `c2`? Also, since you know how long the string will be, you should reserve space for all the characters up front.

```
std::string to_string(char c1, char c2) const
{
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(NumBits);

    for (size_t i = NumBits; i-- > 0;)
        str.push_back(test(i) ? c2 : c1);

    return str;
}
```

You implementation also has bugs: `to_string('0', '1')` results in an infinite loop, and `to_string('1', '0')` always results in a string with all zeroes.

Comment: Oh, may I know why it results in an infinite loop? Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: If you are trying to replace `'0'` with `'0'` while there are still `'0'`s in the string, then you will have an infinite loop.